# Why did I receive reputation for this answer

Tags: discussion

I answered a [C++ question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29873986/my-c-program-cant-recognize-stdstring/29874560#29874560) yesterday which was really something silly committed on behalf of the asker. I just casually added the required header and posted the answer. The question was later on highly downvoted. But what I am seeing now is that I have earned +8 reputation from this question. There are no upvotes on my answer. From where did this +8 reputation came?

Answer (score 9):

There *is* an upvote on the answer. It was upvoted once, and downvoted once:

[image: post voting]

You got +10 for the upvote and -2 for the downvote, for a total reputation change of +8.

You can see the same in [your reputation tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3763293/akshay-arora?tab=reputation&sort=post) if you switch to the *post* view:

[image: post view reputation log]

Comment: 10-2 = 8. oops. Something silly committed on behalf of asker of "this" question. :)

Comment: Err.. just a thought, any reason for the downvote you can think of?

Comment: @AkshayArora: I'm no C++ expert so I cannot judge your post on the technical merrits. I have no idea. Perhaps the voter [lost their keys](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215379/should-drive-by-downvoting-be-more-effectively-caught/215397#215397)?